# Getting hidden values in classic extractor

Tags: extract, import.io

I have a classic extractor that gets some data, including an email. When I train it, I'm asked to tell if I can see the data after clicking on "detecting optimal settings", and since I can't see the email, I hit "no".

The extractor later extracts everything, including the email, but when I save this extractor and want to use it with a bulk of emails, it doesn't work. It just seems it worked for that first time, but it doesn't work again.

Anybody has the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the issue here is the java-script , you can use `http://render.import.io/?url=` add this before all of your links
this will pre-render the pages for import to use in other words it will load all the page before import can extract the data.